# Vertical align text within button

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, menuitem

Trying to vertically align text for the buttons in the middle, however i want entire button are to be a link (not just text) so i stretched the anchor tag, now i cannot vertically align text anymore even if i wrap it in another tag still does not work for some reason.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

hr {
    border:0;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#000000;
}



ul {
    border-spacing:15px;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}

li {
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:75px;
            text-align:center;
}

a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;

    background-color:#FCF;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.5;
}


<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT<HR/>US</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">NEW<hr/>EVENTS</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Key points:

- I like to keep buttons auto stretch to the page width like it is now.
- I like to have entire button area to be click able not just text.
- I like to keep **unordered list** for menu structure as its semantically correct for menu

http://jsfiddle.net/vWrE8/

Final Result Should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKEc8.png

In my opinion wrapping text inside anchor tag with div is a way to go and then valign-middle, however i cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/vWrE8/1/)**

You need to remove the `disiplay:block` from the anchor tags, and vertically align them throught he li element.

CSS

```
    li {
     // other styles here

      vertical-align: middle;
      background-color:#FCF; //<-move the bg to here
    }

    a {
     // other styles here

     // display:block;
     // background-color:#ccc; 
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is good, upvoted it, but dude wants to keep the whole block clickable.

Comment: Yap only text is clickable now not entire button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is achievable without wrapping the multi-line texts in another element, but once that's done, it's quite straightforward. Assuming that wrapper element is a div, just add

```
a div { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
a:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

As per http://jsfiddle.net/vWrE8/9/

Comment: What sorcery is this!?

Answer (score 0):

BadAdviceGuy's solution is good, but given you want whole block to be clickable, you can try fluid padding for the anchor tags. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWrE8/3/)

CSS:

```
a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    padding: 50% 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: How do i adjust height of the buttons to be 75px in this case?

Comment: Erm, okay. Didn't notice that. Well, you're using table structure and overflow won't hide for this. You'll probably need to assign height to the anchor tag, but that might need tuning for every single item.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I can get to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vWrE8/6/

Only works for one line break, after that it falls apart... =/

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
hr {
    border:0;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
ul {
    width:100%;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    background-color:#ccc;
    min-width:110px;
    height:75px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px 10px;
}
a {
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FCF;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.5;
    line-height:2em;
}
a span {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    line-height:1em;
    top:30%;
}

<ul>
    <li> <a href="#"><span>HOME<span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>ABOUT<span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>ABOUT <HR/>US<span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>NEW <HR/>EVENTS<span></a></li>
</ul>
```